# textview not right to left although right to left device

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left

I'm building an app that will work both for RTL and for LTR on local direction , i work with a RTL device (HEBREW) and all views are RTL ok. but on another device a bit newer all views that's text is in Hebrew are right to left but in English they are left to right they supposed to be right to left even if they are in English , already tested on 2 newer phones and yeah this problem again.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change gravity in XML:

```
<TextView android:width="wrap_content"
          android:height="wrap_content"
          android:text="example"
          android:gravity="right"/>
```

You can also change it in code:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: so first i'll check if the device is RTL then if so set the gravity for all textViews who may act different then RTL thanks i'll try this right now.

Answer (score 0):

While working with an app that supports both RTL and LTR, Use values for gravity as START and END

Comment: yep well
i do override even though its RTL the gravity feature for every text view that can contain a string like name or address

Comment: cause i have a hebrew phone , everything is right to left

Comment: but my other friend have also a Hebrew phone but all the text which is in English is left to right although its rtl